# AngularJS ng-class and invalid tab - functionality is broken

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

We have tabs working correctly using this HTML

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 panel-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#general" ng-class="{true: 'invalid-tab', false: ''}[form.editTemplateGeneralForm.$invalid]">@Labels.general</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#startingValues" ng-class="{true: 'invalid-tab', false: ''}[form.editTemplateStartingValuesForm.$invalid]">@Labels.startingValues</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The invalid-tab used to work fine, and when the tab was invalid it was shown in red. Now it's no longer working and we suspect it's the newest version of AngularJS that broke that functionality. We're using v1.3.13.

Do you know what should be adjusted in that syntax above to make it work again (that is used in many pages of our application).

Here is the invalid-tab from our site.css:

```html
.widget .invalid-tab * {
    background-color: #F9EAF3;
    /*color: #F9EAF3;*/
    color: #d43f3a;
}

    .widget .invalid-tab:hover * {
        background-color: #E06B6C;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you just want to set class to invalid-tab if the form field is invalid right?  Simpler version would be as follows:  `ng-class="{'invalid-tab': form.editTemplateGeneralForm.$invalid}"` [edited with syntax fixes]

Comment: Will try that, thanks.

Comment: The problem still remains although this is a shorter syntax. The invalid tab is not shown in red :(

Comment: When you inspect, does it have the invalid-tab class?

Comment: Yes, it's weird. This is what I see when I inspect it: <a data-toggle="pill" href="#general" ng-class="{'invalid-tab': form.editTemplateGeneralForm.$invalid}" class="invalid-tab">General</a>

Comment: So, the class is indeed applied, but the red color is not working :( May be something changed with <a tag and class is no longer recognized on that element? I'm testing in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to define ng-class is as follows: `ng-class="{classname: expresstion}"`

You also need to remove the asterisk from the css-selector - as you are selecting any child element. But the `.invalid-tab` has no child elements.

Another solution would be to move the `.invalid-tab` class out to the parent `li-element`

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('testApp', function(){
    return {
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.form = {
          editTemplateStartingValuesForm: {$invalid: true},
          editTemplateGeneralForm: {$invalid: false}
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.widget .invalid-tab {
    background-color: #F9EAF3;
    /*color: #F9EAF3;*/
    color: #d43f3a;
}

.widget .invalid-tab:hover {
    background-color: #E06B6C;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="widget" test-app>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 panel-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#general" ng-class="{'invalid-tab': form.editTemplateGeneralForm.$invalid}">@Labels.general</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#startingValues" ng-class="{'invalid-tab': form.editTemplateStartingValuesForm.$invalid}">@Labels.startingValues</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I already switched to that format, but for unknown reason it is still not working. I do see class applied when I inspect the element, but it is not shown in red.

Comment: invalid-tab is not a part of the normal bootstrap classes afaik. So seems like there is something wrong with your css. I had to manually add the .invalid-tab in my snippet - even when I imported bootstrap.

Comment: could you please edit it into the original question - much easier to read.

Comment: remove the asterisk (*) from the CSS. It means it selects any child element. But the .invalid-tab has no child elements.